# Giving error that wrong return type in java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, arraylist

I am reading the database in `MySql` and storing the values in the `ArrayList` and return it..

```
public ArrayList getData(String rule) {
    try {
        String q = "select distinct email_id from logs where rule ='" + rule + "';";
        System.out.println(q);
        rs = st.executeQuery(q);
        ArrayList emails = new ArrayList();
        while (rs.next()) {
            emails.add(rs.getString("email_id"));
        }
        return emails;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("" + e);
    }
}
```

what is wrong with this piece of code.. It gives an error that "It must return a result of type `ArrayList`".. But I am returning the 'emails' which is of type `ArrayList` only.. Help me to figure out this error..

Comment: Hint: What happens if exception occurs? What should program do at that case? Isn't it return at that condition. Check all possible flow of execution of your code.

Comment: as a sidenote: [GENERICS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html), don´t use rawtypes..

Comment: You're returning them within the try-block, when an exception occurrs you don't return anything. You could return null in the catch block or just at the end of the method depending on what the objective of the method is.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating your array inside your try scope, create it in your method scope, before the try and return it in the end of your program, so you can use something like this :

```
public ArrayList getData(String rule) {
    ArrayList emails = new ArrayList();//<<----create the list here
    try {
        String q = "select distinct email_id from logs where rule ='" + rule + "';";
        System.out.println(q);
        rs = st.executeQuery(q);
        //ArrayList emails = new ArrayList();<<--------don't create the list here
        while (rs.next()) {
            emails.add(rs.getString("email_id"));
        }
        //return emails;//<<-------don't return the result here
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("" + e);
    }
    return emails;//<<-------return the list here
}
```

---

Another thing, to avoid any Syntax error, or SQL Injection i suggest to use PreparedStatement instead, it is more secure and more helpful, for example :

```
public ArrayList getData(String rule) throws SQLException {
    ArrayList emails = new ArrayList();//
    try (PreparedStatement pstm = connection.prepareStatement(
            "select distinct email_id from logs where rule = ?")) {
        //NOTE: Position indexes start at 1, not 0
        pstm.setString(1, rule);
        ResultSet rs = pstm.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            emails.add(rs.getString("email_id"));
        }
    }

    return emails;
}
```